# how to add additional column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT Count(IN_Invoices.in_id) NoOfInv,
       sum(in_total) AMTsum,
       CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_Id     
  from (select distinct 
               MasterOrderId, 
               cl_Id 
          from CLOI_ClientOrderItems) as CLOI_ClientOrderItems 
       inner Join IN_Invoices 
            on IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
group by 
       CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

The query result is

```
NoOfInv   AMTsum      cl_id
7         245        100000pri
247       181110.29  100001pro
```

Grandtotal,presentmonthtotal,firstpreviousmont,secondpr,remainingamount

i have date of issue column in my table that contained dates
 presentmonthtotal ->need to search it in date of issue column and display that month details

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please give us an input example and the desired output, it will help, a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to combine two results in single query in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681168/how-to-combine-two-results-in-single-query-in-sql)