# how to combine two results in single query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this query

```
Select
     Count(IN_Invoices.in_id) NoOfInv,
     sum(in_total) AMTsum,
     CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_Id     
from
(
    select
        distinct MasterOrderId,
        cl_Id 
    from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
 ) as CLOI_ClientOrderItems 
inner Join IN_Invoices 
  on IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
group by CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

the query result is

```
noofinc  amtsum      cl_id
7         245        100000pri
247       181110.29  100001pro
```

```
Select
    Count(IN_Invoices.in_id) NoOfInv,
    AMTsum=sum(in_total) ,
    CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_Id     
from
(
   select
        distinct MasterOrderId,
        cl_Id 
   from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
) as CLOI_ClientOrderItems 
inner Join IN_Invoices
  on IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=1 and datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014
group by CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

in this queryi haveenterd the month so itll show that month records

```
noofinc  amtsum   cl_id         Grandtotal
5        7.00     100000_Pri    7.00
12       2510.12  100001_pro    2510.12
```

but in this query result showing wrong if i enterd month also it should be show (see the 1st query result of amtsum column)
Grandtotal is

```
 245
 181110.29
```

Comment: The second query can't show the mentioned result because it has 3 columns in its select list instead of 4 mentioned in result.

Comment: in previous query result amtsum column i need to add it in 2nd query

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you use?

Comment: Please don't post the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE to determine if a record is in the desired month. Select all records (no where clause) and use that case expression to decide wether to add a value or ignore it. In below example I have built a flag month_match to enhance readabilty. For this I had to build a sub query first. It's not necessary; I just like it better this way.

```
select 
  cl_id,
  sum( case when month_match = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as count_invoices_in_month,
  sum( case when month_match = 1 then in_total else 0 end ) as sum_invoices_in_month,
  count(*) as count_invoices_total,
  sum( in_total ) as sum_invoices_total
from
(
  select
    i.in_id,
    i.in_total,
    cloi.cl_id,
    case when datepart(mm, i.in_date_issued) = 1
         and datepart(yyyy, i.in_date_issued) = 2014 then
      1
    else
      0
    end as month_match
  from
  (
    select distinct masterorderid, cl_id from cloi_clientorderitems
  ) as cloi
  inner join in_invoices i on i.masterorderid=cloi.masterorderid
)
group by cl_id;
```

Comment: its giving error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'."